# Is the set of all probability measures weak* closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space. Denote by $ba(\Sigma)$ the set of all bounded and finitely additive measures on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space for a definition). Is the set of all probability measures $\mathcal{M}_1(\Sigma)\subseteq ba(\Sigma)$ weak*-closed? The weak*-topology on $ba(\Sigma)$ is the weakest topology such that the maps $l_Z:ba(\Sigma)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, mapping $\mu\mapsto \int_\Omega Z d\mu$, are continuous for all bounded and measurable maps $Z:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You really need to put these questions on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The most elementary case is $\Omega=\mathbb N$ and $\Sigma$ the power set.  A non-fixed ultrafilter is a good example of a finitely-additive but not countably-additive measure:  each set has either measure $0$ or $1$.  But such a thing is a limit of fixed ultrafilters, that is, countably additive zero-one measures.  Indeed, it is the limit along that very ultrafilter.

Nik seems to think this is too elementary.  But there is no reason this should be clear to a non-specialist.

Comment: It's like asking whether the unit ball of $l^1$ is weak* closed in its double dual.

Comment: @Nik: since it *is* weak* sequentially closed, even that is an interesting question.

Comment: Nik: yes, it is exactly like that in the sense that neither is clear to a non-specialist.

Comment: Annoyingly, this is exactly the same as an answer I gave over at math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157795/is-the-set-of-all-probability-measures-weak-closed  I had already suggested to Peter (who may or may not also be Andy) that it was polite to point out when you are cross-posting...

Comment: @Peter: your comment is inappropriate. This is a professional forum and we don't talk that way here.

Comment: @PeterGradov: that was not Matthew's point. His point was is that it goes against the norms of this site (and, in my opinion, basic good manners) to post in different places without alerting people in those places that the question is being worked on elsewhere. He is not claiming that he was the first person to ever answer this question, merely that the question has already be answered elsewhere so that Gerald need not have taken time to write out another answer.

Comment: I have deleted two comments by Peter Gradov.